# JComboBox not returning expected result

Tags: java, jcombobox

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String[] arr = {tf1.getText(),tf2.getText(),"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""};

            switch(cb1.getSelectedItem().toString()){

            case "Hillsborough":
                    arr[2]  = "1";
                    break;

            case "Pinellas":
                    System.out.println("HIT 1");
                    arr[3] = "1";
                    break;
            case "Pasco":
                    System.out.println("HIT 2");
                    arr[4]  = "1";
                    break;
            case "Hernando":
                    System.out.println("HIT 3");
                    arr[5]  = "1";
                    break;
            case "Polk":
                    System.out.println("HIT 3");
                    arr[6] = "1";
                    break;
            case "Manatee":
                    System.out.println("HIT 4");
                    arr[7]  = "1";
                    break;
            case "Sarasota":
                    System.out.println("HIT 5");
                    arr[8]  = "1";
                    break;
            case "Other Florida":
                    System.out.println("HIT 6");
                    arr[9]  = "1";
                    break;
            case "Other State/Country":
                    System.out.println("HIT 7");
                    arr[10]  = "1";
                    break;
            default:
                    break;
            }
            switch(cb2.getSelectedItem().toString()){
            case "Active Duty":
                    arr[11]  = "1";
                    break;
            case "Coalition Forces":
                    arr[12] = "1";
                    break;
            case "Dependent":
                    arr[13]  = "1";
                    break;
            case "Guard/Reserve":
                    arr[14]  = "1";
                    break;
            case "Retired":
                    arr[15] = "1";
                    break;
            case "Veteran":
                    arr[16]  = "1";
                    break;
            case "Civilian":
                    arr[17]  = "1";
                    break;

            default:
                    break;
            }
            reader.submit(2, arr);
            for(int c = 0; c < arr.length;c++)
                    System.out.print(arr[c]);
    }
```

> When i click the confirm button it triggers this. It, depending on the selected result, will add a 1 to a specific spot in the array and the pass it on through another method. It has nothing to do with the second method, the results aren't being accessed at all. The first result in the combo box doesn't have a switch/case associated with it because those are the placeholders for the selction boxes. Any way to fix it?

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And what return cbo.getSelectedItem().toString()?

1. Use a List instead an array. List is dinamic so you can add elements when you need. Using a array when you don't know the length of data is unreadable and unnecessary.

   ```
   List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
   data.add(cbo.getSelectedItem().toString());
   ```
2. Are you sure you've added a String instead an Object? If you've added an Object, when you call to `toString` method you'll get the class and `hashCode` for it. So, if you've added an Object to your combo, you need override the toString method and get back an String (something that identify the Object).

   ```
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "some identifier";
   }
   ```

Comment: I am using a JComboBox and i do know the length of the array. I define the whole thing in the beginning and edit it based on the results returned.

Comment: what return `cbo.getSelectedItem().toString()`?